# Does a firebase client using only 'once()' callbacks count as a concurrent user?

Tags: firebase

I have read [online](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/firebase-talk/4_YzR1xYxRM) that a concurrent user is defined as a client that has an `on()` callback listening for updates on your data. If I use the `once()` method instead throughout my app (in other words, I'm just using firebase as a data store) will the client still count as a concurrent user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will. We count the number of clients (browser tabs or mobile devices) with open connections to us. We open a connection to the Firebase servers as soon as you say `new Firebase(url);`, and we leave it open so that all future requests will be fast (otherwise, the next time you did a `once` or any other operation we'd have to reestablish a connection again, which would slow things down).

Comment: @Andrew  Say a user opens a page that contains three Firebase references (calls new Firebase(url) three times), does that page count as one connection or three? If we create a lot of firebase refs in the code, do we run up the number of connections? Please clarify.

Comment: @Jarnal from what I can tell all the Firebase references on a single Browser Tab or Device would amount to a single concurrent connection. Each separate browser tab, device would be a new concurrent connection.